# Did Koszul introduce Koszul connections?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, math-history, vector-bundles, connections

[Wiki in this article about connections on vector bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)) contains following information:

> Connections on vector bundles are also sometimes called Koszul connections after Jean-Louis Koszul, who gave an algebraic framework for describing them (Koszul 1950 [ref. below]).

I just read referrd paper and I haven't noticed anything which looks like connections.

> **Question**. So does it mean that Koszul only gave and algebraic framework and connections in algebraic language are due to someone
>   else? Or maybe Koszul introduced connections on vector bundles in some
>   other paper?

---

Koszul, J. L. (1950), "Homologie et cohomologie des algebres de Lie", Bulletin de la Société Mathématique, 78: 65–127

Comment: Koszul was a professor "très remarquable" at Grenoble University, extremely severe for putting notes to students.

Comment: @Piquito Sorry, but honestly I see no point in your comment. Could you be more precise? Do you mean that he presented his ideas about connections to students, but did't give them any notes?

Comment: It may be that my deficient English does not make clear what I wanted to say: I spoke about qualification of students who feared him, feared his severity Not at all about papers of research but about Mastery curricula courses.

Comment: @Piquito Thanks for this info, cause I like to hear about behaviour of great mathematicians.

Comment: Bernard Malgrange and Claude Chabauty were  colleages of Koszul at Grenoble. Excellent people very kind.